# Merging every two rows of data in a column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

My table structure is..

```
Id   UserId EventId
  1      1       A    
  2      1       B
  3      1       C
  4      1       A
  5      1       D
```

The output I need..

```
UserId   EventStart   EventEnd
1           A           B
1           B           C
1           C           A
1           A           D
```

I want every two rows to be merged into a row, so if the first row has A and 2nd has B then the first row of result table has A & B..

I have looked into PIVOT but unable to figure out how to get the results I want..

It would be great if I could solve this with sql else if it has to be solved in the middle layer, I'm using C#

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: How you define EvntStart and EventEnd ??? Plz explain in detail...

Comment: Edited the question,please do let know if its clear..Tx..

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "next" row in a table unless a column specifies the ordering.  Does your table have an id or creation date column with this information?

Comment: I have an Id as well as creation date, I thought they were not necesary, so did not add to the structure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have have an id column that specifies the ordering, you can get what you want using `lead()` (in SQL Server 2012+):

```
select userId, eventid as eventstart,
       lead(eventid) over (partition by userid order by id) as eventend
from mytable t;
```

You are filtering out the last row, which you can do with a subquery (window functions aren't allowed in the `where` clause):

```
select t.*
from (select userId, eventid as eventstart,
             lead(eventid) over (partition by userid order by id) as eventend
      from mytable t
     ) t
where eventend is null;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can get the same effect in other ways, such as a correlated subquery or cross apply.  Here is an example:

```
select t.*
from (select userId, eventid as eventstart,
             (select top 1 t2.eventid
              from mytable t2
              where t2.userid = t.userid and
                    t2.id > t.id
              order by t2.id
             ) as eventend
      from mytable t
     ) t
where eventend is not null;
```

Comment: I have sql server 2008 locally but I will be hosting at sql azure, for testing I'm using correlated subquery- here 'my table name' will replace t or t2?

Comment: I think the last part of query should be 'where eventend is not null;'

Comment: @Amab . . . I totally misread your comment.  My apologies, you are -- of course -- correct.

Comment: any idea why an Or clause does not work inside where clause here..I tried "where eventstart != 'A' " -this worked but when I tried "where eventstart != 'A' Or eventstart != 'B' " - this did not..

Comment: @Amab . . . I don't know what your question is referring to.  But if you want neither A nor B, just use `not in`:  `eventstart not in ('A', 'B')`.

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach would be using a CTE with a generated Row_Number() over the ID and joining over UserID and Rownumber.

```
declare @t  Table([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, UserID int,EventID varchar(10))
insert into @t
Select 1,'A'
UNION ALL Select 1,'B'
UNION ALL Select 1,'C'
UNION ALL Select 1,'A'
UNION ALL Select 1,'D'
UNION ALL Select 2,'B'
UNION ALL Select 2,'C'
UNION ALL Select 2,'A'
UNION ALL Select 2,'D'


;With c as
(
Select UserID,EventID,Row_Number() OVER (Order by UserID,ID ) as RN
from @t
)
Select c1.UserID,c1.EventID as EventStart ,c2.EventID as EventEnd
from c c1
Join c c2 on c2.RN=c1.RN+1 and c2.UserID=c1.UserID
```

Comment: I have 8462 rows of data of 64 users.., With just the bottom part of your answer, I get 5084 rows which is less..

Comment: Yes, now I get the same result as the answer from Gordon-Tx