# Logic to read multiple rows in a table where flag = 'Y'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Consider the following scenario. I have a Customer table, which includes RowStart and EndDate logic, thus writing a new row every time a field value is updated.

Relevant fields in this table are:

- `RowStartDate`
- `RowEndDate`
- `CustomerNumber`
- `EmployeeFlag`

For this, I'd like to write a query, which will return an employee's period of tenure (`EmploymentStartDate`, and `EmploymentEndDate`). I.e. The `RowStartDate` when `EmployeeFlag` first became 'Y', and then the first `RowStartDate` where `EmployeeFlag` changed to 'N' (Ordered of course, by the RowStartDate asc). There is an additional complexity in that the Flag value may change between Y and N multiple times for a single person, as they may become staff, resign and then be employed again at a later date.

```
Example table structure is:
| CustomerNo | StaffFlag | RowStartDate | RowEndDate |
| ---------- | --------- | ------------ | ---------- |
| 12         | N         | 2019-01-01   | 2019-01-14 |
| 12         | N         | 2019-01-14   | 2019-03-02 |
| 12         | Y         | 2019-03-02   | 2019-10-12 |
| 01         | Y         | 2020-03-13   | NULL       |
| 12         | N         | 2019-10-12   | 2020-01-01 |
| 12         | Y         | 2020-01-01   | NULL       |
```

Output could be something like

```
| CustomerNo | StaffStartDate | StaffEndDate |
| ---------- | -------------- | ------------ |
| 12         | 2019-03-02     | 2019-10-12   |
| 01         | 2020-03-13     | NULL         |
| 12         | 2021-01-01     | NULL         |
```

Any ideas on how I might be able to solve this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired outputs would help.

Comment: Tried adding a table to show output and table structure, formatting doesnt seem to be working

Comment: `SELECT <fields> FROM YourTable WHERE StaffFlag = 'Y'`?

Comment: From your example, the rows with `N` flag seem to be completely irrelevant, so just `select  * from table where staffflag = 'Y'` If that doesn't meed your requirements, you need a better example illustrating the actual problem.

Comment: Agreed your sample data is likely not representative of your actual goal, your desired results is simply the rows where the flag='Y'. Also, note you appear to be reinventing the wheel here as SQL Server has built-in support for this kind of data using *temporal tables*.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you order the columns by ID and by dates:

```
select * 
from yourtable
order by CustomerNumber asc, 
EmployeeFlag desc,
RowStartDate asc, 
RowEndDate asc
```

This gives you a list of all changes over time per employee.

Subsequently, you want to map two rows into a single row with two columns (two dates mapped into overall start and end date). Others have done this using the `lead()` function. For details please have a look here: [Merging every two rows of data in a column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136683/merging-every-two-rows-of-data-in-a-column-in-sql-server)